# Mystery integral in the first issue of Annals of Mathematics

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, math-history

[Vol 1. No. 1](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1967417?socuuid=&seq=2) of *Annals of Mathematics* has an "Exercises" section with [this unusual integral](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ngvV.jpg) sent in by a Professor Lewis Green Barbour:

$$\int_{\frac \pi 2}^\pi \sqrt{1-\frac 1 2 \cos^2\vartheta + \sin\vartheta\sin2\vartheta}\,{\rm d}\vartheta$$

The other exercises are answered in later issues but this one seems to have been quietly forgotten.

I've tried modern software and it's stumped on solving the indefinite integral. Numerical methods yield a value:

$$\approx 0.8277600029391442$$

However, this doesn't seem to be a closed-form number in any obvious way. Searches of various number databases turn up nothing.

Does this integral have a closed-form solution? If not, what methods would a reader in 1884 have used to solve it? Given how famous the *Annals* became, does this unsolved exercise from the very first issue have any lore attached to it?

Comment: Just a side question for myself, but is it normal to exclude $\mathrm{d}\vartheta$ as done in the original text? A peculiarity of the 1800s, or a typo?

Comment: @Scene I'm not sure about the 1800s, but viewed in the context of today's writing, it's not typical, but also not unusual.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2947883/how-to-evaluate-int-pi-2-pi-sqrt1-frac12-cos2-x-sin-x-sin-2x?noredirect=1

Comment: @AndrewZhang thanks!

Comment: amazing first question; probably set a record for the most votes on a question closed within 30 minutes

Comment: The answers in the duplicate are not that satisfactory. One of them does not even give the correct value.

Comment: @Gary Right, the OP on this post mentions the methods should be accessible to a reader in 1884. The accepted answer in the duplicate doesn't seem to satisfy the requirements. Is this not enough to keep this post open?

Comment: @Scene Well, the methods in that answer were easily available in 1884. The OP here asks if there is closed form solution. I wonder if L. G. Barbour thought about solving it in a closed form or just evaluating it numerically.

Comment: Is it a coincidence that [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1401.3987.pdf) has the constant $0.827760$? Based on some of the stuff that pops up in the accepted answer in the duplicate [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2947883/how-to-evaluate-int-pi-2-pi-sqrt1-frac12-cos2-x-sin-x-sin-2x), I might think not.

Comment: The Taylor series, binomial series, and beta/gamma function in the duplicate answer all were found before 1800, after some quick references. Which part of the duplicate, besides the Zeilberger algorithm and Mathematica which can be ignored in the answer, is not accessible to a reader in 1884?

Comment: If the author of the problem happens to match the person described in the following link, https://www.pcahistory.org/HCLibrary/periodicals/spr/bios/barbour.html, then the title matches the passage from there, i'm citing: *L.G. Barbour's publication efforts included a book, The End of Time: A Poem of the Future, (New York: G.P. Putnam's Sons, 1892); articles and pamphlets on mathematics; two articles in The Presbyterian Quarterly; and several articles in The Southern Presbyterian Review including ones on the subjects of logic, natural theology, and* **mysticism.**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$I=\int\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{2} \cos ^2(x)+\sin (x) \sin (2 x)}\,dx$$ Using multiple angle formulae
$$I=\frac 12 \int \sqrt{3+2 \cos (x)-\cos (2 x)-2 \cos (3 x)}\,dx$$
$$x=\cos^{-1}(t) \quad \implies \quad I=-\frac 12 \int \sqrt{\frac{4+8 t-2 t^2-8 t^3 }{1-t^2  }}\,dt$$

The integrand is minimum at a point where
$$2t^4-4 t^2+t+2=0$$ and we know the exact value of the root $a$ of interest.

$$J=\int_{\frac \pi 2}^\pi\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{2} \cos ^2(x)+\sin (x) \sin (2 x)}\,dx$$
$$J=\frac 12 \int_{-1}^a \sqrt{\frac{4+8 t-2 t^2-8 t^3 }{1-t^2  }}\,dt+\frac 12 \int_{a}^0 \sqrt{\frac{4+8 t-2 t^2-8 t^3 }{1-t^2  }}\,dt$$ For each integral, using series expansion around each bound of $t$. Integrating termwise and converting to decimals

$$\frac 12 \int_{-1}^a \cdots \,dt =0.418355365493$$
$$\frac 12 \int_{a}^0 \cdots \,dt  =0.409404637296$$
make a total of
$$\frac 12 \int_{-1}^0 \cdots \,dt=  \color{red}{0.827760002}79$$
to be compared to                   $\color{red}{0.82776000294}$

Comment: What does the series expansion look like?

Comment: @TymaGaidash. They are very trivial around $t=-1$ and $t=0$. My only problem is that I did not find the general formula for the coefficients. Around $t=-1$, in fact, it is a Laurent series.

Comment: Typo in the third display line: leading minus sign in the expression for $I$?

Comment: @JohnBentin. I think that it is correct

Comment: OK, I get it now. The change of variable is a decreasing function, so the order of the integral limits, when a definite integral is evaluated, will be “the wrong way round”.

Comment: In the fourth display line, the equation $t^4-4t^2+t+2=0$ factorizes as $$(t-1)(t+2)(t^2-t-1)=0.$$ So the only root in the range $|t|<1$ is $t=-\varphi^{-1}=-0.618...$. When I calculated the expression for the minimum, I got the coefficient of $t^4$ in the quartic as $2$, not $1$ as you have it. Could you check again, please?

Comment: @JohnBentin. You are right ! Thanks for pointing it.

Answer (score 5):

The problem being to compute $$I=\frac 12 \int_{\frac \pi 2}^\pi \sqrt{3+2 \cos (x)-\cos (2 x)-2 \cos (3 x)}\,dx$$ the integrand is minimum at
$$x_*=\pi -\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)$$

Using series expansion around $x=\frac \pi 2$
$$\frac 12 \sqrt{3+2 \cos (x)-\cos (2 x)-2 \cos (3 x)}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n\left(x-\frac{\pi }{2}\right)^n$$
$$I_1=\frac 12 \int_{\frac \pi 2}^{x_*} \sqrt{3+2 \cos (x)-\cos (2 x)-2 \cos (3 x)}\,dx$$
$$\color{blue}{I_1=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a_n}{(n+1)}\left(\frac{\pi }{2}-\tan
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)\right)^{n+1}}$$ Around $x=\pi$
$$\frac 12 \sqrt{3+2 \cos (x)-\cos (2 x)-2 \cos (3 x)}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n\left(\pi-x\right)^{2n}$$
$$I_2=\frac 12 \int_{x_*}^{\pi} \sqrt{3+2 \cos (x)-\cos (2 x)-2 \cos (3 x)}\,dx$$
$$\color{blue}{I_2=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{b_n}{(2n+1)}\left(\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)\right)^{2 n+1}}$$

The required coefficients are explicitly known from those of the square of the integrand (they are simple).

Then, the result.

**Edit**

Defining
$$S_p=\sum_{n=0}^{2p} \frac{a_n}{(n+1)}\left(\frac{\pi }{2}-\tan
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)\right)^{n+1}+\sum_{n=0}^p \frac{b_n}{(2n+1)}\left(\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)\right)^{2 n+1}$$ we have a very slow converging oscillating series (as @user2249675 mentioned [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2947883/how-to-evaluate-int-pi-2-pi-sqrt1-frac12-cos2-x-sin-x-sin-2x)) and the first time the string $0.8277600$ appears is for $p=90$.

I used the same procedure for the integral between $0$ and $\pi$, splitting the interval in three regions
$$0 \leq x \leq \frac \pi 3 \qquad  \frac \pi 3 \leq x \leq \pi -\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)\qquad \pi -\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}\right) \leq x \leq \pi$$

Answer (score 2):

By using the Maclaurin series $\sqrt{1+x}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}{2n\choose n}}{4^n(2n-1)}x^n$, the given integral $\int_0^1\frac{\sqrt{1+(1-t^2)(1-4t)}}{\sqrt2\,\sqrt{1-t^2}}dt$ can be written as
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}{2n\choose n}}{4^n\,\sqrt2\,(2n-1)}\int_0^1(1-4t)^n(1-t^2)^{n-\frac12}dt$$
and
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}{2n\choose n}}{4^n\,\sqrt2\,(2n-1)}\int_0^{\pi/2}(1-4\sin\theta)^n(\cos\theta)^{2n}\,d\theta$$
where the integral $\int_0^{\pi/2}(1-4\sin\theta)^n(\cos\theta)^{2n}\,d\theta=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k2^{2k-1}{n\choose k}B(k+1,2n+1)$ can be expressed in terms of beta functions.

Comment: This is the same as https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2949174/471884 which has greater detail

Comment: $t$-version is not there...

Comment: @TheSimpliFire The question is the same.